# Проблемы с отображением видео из Ютуба на мобильном

Tags: mobile, видео, html5

Есть ссылка из youtube:

> `http://www.youtube.com/v/D8lR7tIoTiM?version=3&f=user_uploads&app=youtube_gdata`

Нужно, чтобы на мобильном отображало данное видео. Пробовал через `<embed>` и через `<iframe>`.  На телефоне ни то, ни другое не отображается. Возможно, дело в видео, и мне нужно видео с мобильной версии ютуба или можно как-то и с этим решить проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вставлять видео [этим](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html) способом:

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385"     src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/D8lR7tIoTiM" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Если же и это не сработает, то скорее всего мобильное устройство не поддерживает ни Flash, ни HTML5 video.